# How to integrate an oracle database with an asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, integration

How to integrate an oracle database with an asp.net web application?... Any good tutorial to start with?

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/vs2010-oracle-dev-410461.html) might help you:

> In this article, I'll explain the basic yet essential processes
>   involved in building a C# or Visual Basic .NET application that uses
>   an Oracle database, including:
>
> - How to add project references to support Oracle class libraries in your .NET project
> - How to create Oracle Database connection strings
> - How to work with Connection, Command, and DataReader objects